# IntelliJ Java compile can't find symbol of attached modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotswap

I love the hot swap feature of Java and i'm using it a lot while debugging. I can't compile single classes that contains references to a class from another module in IntelliJ though (with CTRL + SHIFT + F9).
The error I get is the common *java: cannot find symbol*. Seems that the compiler doesn't see the other module.

The module is included under Project structure. Should I configure something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilation with dependencies works only using Build | Make.

Comment: What is it called now? Build project?